# PHP Show my username always front when favorited post

Tags: php

I have PHP code that the function is to show who favorited the post.

The function is running OK, but now facing problem when I'm not the first favorite.

The data display will show :
User A, User B, You favorited this.

But if I'm the first favorited, will show correct like this :
You, User A, User B favorited this. <-- that I wanted.

And here is the PHP code :

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT U.username, U.uid, U.full_name, M.uid_fk FROM tb_favorite M, tb_user U WHERE U.uid = M.uid_fk AND M.msg_id_fk = '$get_post_id' LIMIT 3");
$new_like_count = $get_like_count - 3;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $like_uid = $row['uid_fk'];
    $likeusername = $row['username'];
    $likefull_name = $row['full_name'];

    if($like_uid == $uid)
    {
        echo '<span id="you'.$get_post_id.'"><a href="'.$likeusername.'">You</a>, </span>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="'.$likeusername.'">'.$likefull_name.' </a>';
    } 
}

if($new_like_count < 1)
{
    echo ' favorited this';
}
else
{
    echo 'and '.$new_like_count.' other friends favorited this';
}
```

Comment: Get all your results in an array first and then check if you are in the array and print yourself first

Comment: Do you have any example of that? @ElefantPhace ?

Comment: im surprised this worked `mysqli_query(query)`, first argument should the the connection. but anyway, another way is to put your name on another container, then just unshift it before presenting,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a blank string to append / prepend characters conditionally and print it at last. Consider this:

```
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT U.username, U.uid, U.full_name, M.uid_fk FROM tb_favorite M, tb_user U WHERE U.uid = M.uid_fk AND M.msg_id_fk = '$get_post_id' LIMIT 3");
    $new_like_count = $get_like_count - 3;

    $customString = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $like_uid = $row['uid_fk'];
        $likeusername = $row['username'];
        $likefull_name = $row['full_name'];

        if($like_uid == $uid)
        {
            $customString = '<span id="you'.$get_post_id.'"><a href="'.$likeusername.'">You</a>, </span>'.$customString; // Prepend
        }
        else
        {
            $customString .= '<a href="'.$likeusername.'">'.$likefull_name.' </a>'; //Append
        } 
    }

    if($new_like_count < 1)
    {
        $customString .= ' favorited this';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $customString.'and '.$new_like_count.' other friends favorited this';
    }
```

Comment: I tried and the result : Dudi Aditya You, Dudi Aditya You, Dudi Aditya favorited this